# Socket.io client (nodejs) not connecting to my Socket.io server (golang)

Tags: node.js, go, socket.io

I'm trying to connect a Socket.io nodejs client to my golang Socket.io server.
I'm building an app which will have react frontend and golang backend, and I thought using sockets for the comunication in between would be the best idea (I don't really know if its the best idea but it's the one that I found more useful and which fits to my needs).

My golang server code is taken from this example here https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/blob/master/_examples/default-http/main.go

And my nodejs code looks like this:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io("http://localhost:8000", {
    autoConnect: false,
})

socket.connect();

socket.emit("notice", "test");
```

My golang server is running properly and I've tested that making a GET request with `?EIO=4&transport=polling`

The nodejs client is just not connecting and I don't know why, I've tried connecting on same port, using CORS config, etc but nothing seems to work and I'am unable to connect. I'm not getting any error either from the golang server or the nodejs client, just not connecting.

Appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: Your issue is that the server and client are on different version. You must be using the latest server on your client side while GO library attached only supports till version 1.4
There is a work around that I can share if you are interested.